# Python Logging overhead with function in argument

Tags: python, logging

I am using python logging module (python 3.4.3). 
Let's say my logging level is set to INFO and I would like to use a function as an argument of my logging message.

Now I would expect when log level is decreased (e.g. WARNING) that the argument functions are not executed.

Is this true?

Example (console):

```
>>> import math
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
>>> logging.debug('Factorial of 100000=',math.factorial(100000))
>>> */empty output but slightly delayed, small CPU peak/*
>>> logging.debug('Factorial of 10=',math.factorial(10))
>>> */empty output but instant, no noticeable CPU usage/*
```

The function is probably not executed, but still there is noticable delay. Could someone explain me please the possible cause?

Answer (score 3):

### Function arguments evaluations before call

Well you see the arguments you pass to `logging.debug('Factorial of 100000=', math.factorial(100000))` need to be ***evaluated*** before `logging.debug()` gets *called*, and evaluating `math.factorial(100000)` takes time

It doesn't matter if ultimately the function does nothing in its call, the arguments will still get evaluated

Conceptually you can think of it as doing

```
value = math.factorial(100000)           # This gets evaluated
logging.debug('Factorial is %d', value)  # Even if this is a "no op" call, 
                                         # the arg evaluation still takes place
```

### Workaround

```
import math
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()

if logger.getEffectiveLevel() <= logging.DEBUG:    # Or use == if you want DEBUG only
    logger.debug('Factorial is %d', math.factorial(100000))
```

Using Python 3's [logger.getEffectiveLevel()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.getEffectiveLevel)

Given that the levels are ordered as

```
CRITICAL    50
ERROR       40
WARNING     30
INFO        20
DEBUG       10
NOTSET      0
```

You can see that our if block (with `<= logging.DEBUG`) will only run on `DEBUG` and below (so `DEBUG` and `NOTSET`)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you evaluate the function before you call. One way of dealing with this is using `logger.getEffectiveLevel()` as described by bakkal. This can be a bit verbose though. Another way to get around this is to create an intermediary object to pass to the logger that does the work in it's `__str__` function. This delays the function call until the logging module is sure the message will be emitted.

For example:

```
import logging
import math

class CallableMsg:
    def __init__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs))

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# single arg log
logging.info(CallableMsg(math.factorial, 10)) 
# using the CallableMsg in a format string
logging.info("10! = %s", CallableMsg(math.factorial, 10))
# factorial function never gets evaluated for the debug call
logging.debug(CallableMsg(math.factorial, 1000000))
```

The logging module is also kind enough to preserve the line on which the log call was actually made if there is ever an error.

```
logging.info(CallableMsg(math.factorial, -1))
```

Outputs:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 971, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 821, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 558, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 319, in getMessage
    msg = str(self.msg)
  File "C:python\run.py", line 12, in __str__
    return str(self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs))
ValueError: factorial() not defined for negative values
Call stack:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 126, in main
    ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 353, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "C:\python\run.py", line 18, in <module>
    logging.info(CallableMsg(math.factorial, -1))
Message: <__main__.CallableMsg object at 0x02ECF970>
Arguments: ()
```